# Launch ExceptionValidationRule from specific context

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, exception

**I have a class Client :**

```
public class Client : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string m_strCode;
    public string strCode
    {
        get { return m_strCode; }
        set
        {

            if (CodeIsValide(strCode))
            {                  
                m_strCode = value;
                FirePropertyChangedEvent("strCode");

            }
            else
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("bad Data !");
            }

            FirePropertyChangedEvent("strCode");

        }
    }

    private string m_strName;
    public string strName
    {
        get { return m_strName; }
        set
        {

            if (NameIsValide(strName))
            {
                m_strName = value;
                FirePropertyChangedEvent("strName");

            }
            else
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Bad Data! ");
            }

            FirePropertyChangedEvent("strName");

        }
    }

    public Client(string Code, string Name)
    {
        strCode = Code;
        strName = Name;
    }

    public Client()
    {

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void FirePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

On my WPF Window, i have two textbox : on for client.strCode, and the other for client.strNom.

**Here is the XAML :**

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox_Code"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Height="25"
         Margin="106,230,0,0"
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Width="78">
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="strCode"
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <ExceptionValidationRule />
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>

<TextBox x:Name="TextBox_Name"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Height="25"
         Margin="106,230,0,0"
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Width="78">
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="strName"
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <ExceptionValidationRule />
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

The data input are verifiyng with the ValidationProcess. If the validation is false, it appear a warning label near the textbox.

My problem is : If i load bad data ( from a DataBase) to a Collection of Client object. The load use the set() of my strCode and strName, and, if the data are bad, the ExceptionValidationRule cannot be throwing ( I think it's because the ExceptionValidationRule is not invoked from the textbox binded). ( I'm not English, it's not esay to explain sorry).

I think i need to specify when i want to invoke the verifiy process.

Anyone have advices please ?

If anyone want, i create a sample VS project in order to share my problem.

**EDIT :** If i use a Custom Validator class, it OK !

Just a question, in order to force the validation test, i need to do this, when i select the line in my DataGrid :

```
    private void myDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Affiche le code évt sélectionné dans le tableau, dans les champs modifiable ( en haut de l'écran )

        var item = myDataGrid.SelectedItem as Client;
        if ((item != null))
        {
            TextBox_Code.Text = item.strCode;
            TextBox_Name.Text = item.strName;
        }
    }
```

:

```
TextBox_Code.Text = item.strCode;
TextBox_Name.Text = item.strName;
```

If i remove this two line, the textbox are corectly initialized because of the binding, but the validation process is not invoked. Why ? Is there a way to force the the validation process and use the full binding whitout :

```
TextBox_Code.Text = item.strCode;
TextBox_Name.Text = item.strName;
```

Thanks :)

Thanks a lot :)

Best regards,

Nixeus :)

Comment: so do you not want to have your exception throw when the property is getting assigned from the database load? This would then be a classic case of why people do not prefer ExceptionValidationRule and throwing from setters and instead just use a custom ValidationRule and assign it directly to the xaml and not have the VM involved in it at all.

Comment: Yes, but...is not there a simply way ? Maybe just using the trigger no ?

Comment: I've added an answer showing a workaround, but do remember simple ain't always good. Don't get what you mean by using Trigger. how are Triggers involved in this?

Comment: Please don't edit your questions to append new questions. Just create a new question and keep the original one intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if I understand what your requiring correctly,

You do not want your exceptions raised if the property is set from anything apart from the xaml view.

My preferred solution would be to not use `ExceptionValidationRule` at all and prefer a Custom `ValidationRule`. This will solve your issue. [Example](http://developingfor.net/2009/10/13/using-custom-validation-rules-in-wpf/) shows how to create and use such a feature.

Example for a Custom Validation Rule:

```
public class CodeRangeRule : ValidationRule {
  public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo) {
    int strCode = -1;
    if (value != null && !Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), out strCode))
      return new ValidationResult(false, "Illegal strCode");
    if (strCode < 9999 && strCode > 0) // Modify to suit your Validity Conditions
      return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    return new ValidationResult(false, "strCode is not within acceptable code range");
  }
}
```

and your xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox_Code" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="106,230,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="78">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="strCode"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:CodeRangeRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

**OR**

If you do not want to use a Custom `ValidationRule` for whatever reason, you can keep your `ExceptionValidationRule` as it is in your view and either add a try catch before calling a setter from database load or in your

```
public class Client : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

add another property(say an enum with values `kDatabaseLoad`, `kView`) to indicate if the object is worked on by the View / Database. Thus in the setter of your `strCode` and `strName` check if this enum is `kView` before throwing your exception.

Now when you do a database load and create `Client` objects assign it's enum to `kDatabaseLoad` before setting `strName` and `strCode`. Make sure to switch the enum back to `kView` once done with the load.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer :) I have see the link, and i would like to create a Custom ValidationRule in another class. My problem is i don't know how know where is my current field name. Could you please give me an example of the Custom ValidationRule class for the  strCode for example ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni have updated my answer to include an example of a Custom ValidationRule for strCode. You'll have to update the check for validity in the Validate function. I've just put some dummy condition with a comment you can remove and update accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! for the "<local:CodeRangeRule/>", i have a compilation error, i don't know how to reference the CodeRangeRule? Could you give me the right syntax please ? Thanks :)

Comment: I added this : xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomValidation" but i cannot compile : <local:CodeRangeRule/>

Comment: Maybe I need to instanciate a CodeRangeRule object ? But where ?

Comment: "local:.." refers to the namespace in which you have your "CodeRangeRule" class declared. You normally add that to your root xaml element. read this to understand how to declare xaml namespaces http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms747086.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It's better  ! The validatio now is ok :) ! I edit my post with my code an a little question :) Thanks